# Converting string to float in C?

Tags: c, string, file, structure

Right, So in my C program i have a function that takes a float value from file, and here i am trying to do the reverse, taking the string and turning it into a float.

```
 float PsSc = atoi(stock01[DataCount].defPsSc);
```

I know my error, i assumed it would work for both integers and floats, it doesn't.

I have tried

```
 float PsSc = atof(stock01[DataCount].defPsSc);
```

and that doesn't work either.

So, My question is: What can i replace my current line of code with to make it work?

Input: 1.45 . Expected output: 1.45, Real output: 1.00

Edit:

```
 printf("\nYour previous speed was : %.2f Metres per Second",PsSc);
```

Comment: How are you concluding that the output is `1.00` how are you printing it?

Comment: are you using `printf("%f...`?

Comment: Show ALL relevant code.

Comment: `atof` returns `double` type.

Comment: What does "it does not work either" **mean**?

Comment: `atoi` will not work at all as it will get just the integer part. what does: `printf("%s\n", stock01[DataCount].defPsSc)` print?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`). And test that `scanf` (or `strtod`) don't fail.

Comment: Why down vote on this question.I think its good question.

Comment: @dmg It should print the file content, which is a string of (example) 4.55

Comment: @shan Most of the time they usually never know the answer so they just downvote it.

Comment: @ThatBlueJuice don't give us an "example", show us that it actually prints "1.45" and `atof` and `printf("%f...` prints "1.00". It's hard to understand what is going on here.

Comment: What type of variable is `stock01[DataCount].defPsSc` here? Also, what's `DataCount`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why we shouldn't use atof**

On success, atof() function returns the converted floating point number as a double value. If no valid conversion could be performed, the function returns zero (0.0). If the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by a double, it causes **undefined behavior**.

instead we should use `strtod()` present in `<stdlib.h>`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char s[] = "1.45";
    printf("Float value : %4.2f\n",strtod(s,NULL));
    return 0;
}
```

it will correctly prints 1.45

See the illustration here http://ideone.com/poalgY

Comment: So in this case i write _printf("Value: %.2f",strtod(stock01[DataCount].defPsSc ,NULL));_?

Comment: I guess so as we don't know what is `stock01[DataCount].defPsSc`

Comment: You make a long-winded point about preferring `strtod` over `atof` and then show an example, where you use `strtod` exactly as you would use `atof`.

Comment: @ThatBlueJuice:Yeah it should work if karma is in our favour.

Comment: @Shan: I haven't downvoted anything. I've just made a comment that your example doesn't really promote your assertions that `atof` shouldn't be used. (I think in its current form, `atof` just calls `strtod` the way you do. My Linux manpage says: "The behaviour (of `atof(p)`) is the same as `strtod(p, NULL)` except that `atof()` does not detect errors")

Comment: I thought that the [return value was undefined for *any* non-numeric value](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/atof.html). *The `atof()` function shall return the converted value if the value can be represented.* ... *If the value cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: The downvote was mine. You pointed out the avoidance of UB in case of overflow, but 1) did not mention the use of the second parameter, 2) did not *check* for the overflow, 3) did not mention the locale-dependence of the decimal point. Assuming the OP was correct when saying that `atof()` did not work for him, `strtod( ..., NULL )` won't help him either as it would be identical except for the overflow handling (which `"1.45"` would not trigger). Since the OP accepted your answer, we have to assume he forgot to recompile after changing `atoi` to `atof`... no hard feelings, still >= +13 rep.

Answer (score 2):

The [`strtod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) function family is what you are looking for.

Not only will `strtod()` convert the input string to a `double` (with `strtof()` for `float` and `strtold()` for `long double`), it also tells you exactly where it *stopped* parsing the input string (through the second parameter).

Note that it is locale-dependent whether either `strtod()` or `atof()` expect a decimal *point* or a decimal *comma*...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // play with "." vs. "," to see why this might be your problem
    char * input = "1.45";

    // will take a pointer beyond the last character parsed
    char * end_ptr;

    // strto...() might give an error
    errno = 0;

    // convert
    float result = strtof( input, &end_ptr );

    if ( errno == ERANGE )
    {
        // handle out-of-range error - result will be HUGE_VALF
        puts( "out of range" );
    }

    if ( end_ptr != ( input + strlen( input ) ) )
    {
        // handle incomplete parse
        printf( "Unparsed: '%s'\n", end_ptr );
    }

    printf( "result: %.2f\n", result );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: float PsSc = strtod(stock01[DataCount].defPsSc); ?

Comment: @ThatBlueJuice: Since I have positively **no** idea what `stock01[DataCount].defPsSc` actually **is** (you did not give us that info in your question - your **input** might be bugged already...), I have no idea. Besides, I would implore you to **read the documentation** of a function before using it, as that would have told you that the function takes **two** parameters.

Comment: stock01[DataCount].defPsSc is a string.

Comment: @ThatBlueJuice: That's what **you** say. Check your assumptions. If it were actually a string containing "1.45", your `atof()` should have worked already. What's your locale setting by the way? You might be looking at decimal point vs. decimal comma issues.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `sscanf`which is much more specific:

Reference : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/

```
float PsSc;

sscanf(stock01[DataCount].defPsSc, "%f", &PsSc);
```

Example : http://ideone.com/BaPmDj

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char * str = "1.45";

    float flt;

    sscanf(str, "%f", &flt);

    printf("value = %f\n", flt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sscanf()` is certainly *not* "more specific" than a direct `atof()` call.

Comment: I meant that you can specify what ever type you like.

Comment: Surely that would be "more general" than "more specific" then? :)

Comment: Using `*scanf()` without checking the return value is an uninitialized variable (and hence undefined behavior) waiting to happen. And generally, using `*scanf()` for anything other than known-good formatted data is discouraged. Under virtually every `*scanf()`-related question you will find the suggestion to use `strtod()`/`strtol()` instead -- not the other way around.