# Putting value of a char array into a float variable

Tags: c, arrays, floating-point

I want to put the value of an `array` into a float integer.

```
main(){
    float a;
    char array[4]="12.1";
    a=atoi(array);
    printf("%f",a);
}
```

When I uses this program, it gives `12.000000` as output but I want `12.100000` as output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect from a function whose name is _Ascii To Integer_?

Comment: So which function I need to use?

Comment: Slighy off topic: Oups: `"12.1"` needs 5 chars. You forgot the NUL terminator. Better write `char array[] = "12.1";`, then the length of the array will automatically be determined by the compiler.

Comment: Its still not working @Jabberwocky

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ASCII string to int/float/long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085407/convert-ascii-string-to-int-float-long)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to float in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986672/converting-string-to-float-in-c)

Comment: @Saurabh consider also the answers below.

Comment: `char array[4]="12.1";` is one too few. Use `char array[]="12.1";`

Comment: @Sneftel I don't want to print value as float. I want to transfer that value into a float variable.

Comment: @Saurabh Yes, that's what the person asking the linked question wanted to do as well.

Comment: Sorry guys I am noob. So, if u can remove your downvotes that will be grateful to me.

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of this :

`atof()` — Convert Character String to Float :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double atof(const char *string);
```

[This link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/itof.htm) explains about that.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing the answers and comments, your program should look like:

```
int main(void) {
    float a;
    char array[]="12.1";
    a=atof(array);
    printf("%f\n",a);
}
```

Comment: Output is 858993472.000000

Comment: Btw I am using tcc. So if there is problem with compiler then i will use gcc.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't including library file.

Comment: Yes, for completeness the answer should include `#include <stdlib.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`

Answer (score 2):

instead of `atoi ()` which converts character array to integer, use `atof()` read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)